# Forward get request from one node.js server to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, get

I currently have two instances of nodejs servers running, both listening on localhost, with instance 1 on port 15000 and instance 2 on port 16000.  The first is going to work as a master with the second as part of a group of slaves, where any request coming into the first gets forwarded to the second.

I'm having trouble sending any messages from the first to the second.

```
var jquery = require('jquery');  
jquery.get('http://localhost:16000');
```

called from the first does not get received by the second (jquery is loaded correctly).  I'm about to try Mootools, but would like some advice on the best way to forward an incoming nodejs request directly to another instance of a nodejs server.

Comment: ._. What are you doing. dont use jquery in node. Create a `HTTPClient`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [`cluster`](http://learnboost.github.com/cluster/).

You simply call `cluster` with an instance of a [`http.Server`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/all.html#http.Server) or [`net.Server`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/all.html#net.Server) and it does the load balancing for you.

If you want to roll out something yourself then call your clients with [`http.request`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/all.html#http.request) which is a sensible way to send a HTTP request to a particular server in node.js.

Using jQuery or MooTools to do this for you is horrible (They don't use native C goodness, like standard node.js modules do!). Don't do this. The only reason why you would want jQuery / MooTools in node is to manipulate [`jsdom`](http://www.jsdom.org/)

Comment: Does cluster automatically load balance the server's job? Meaning, does cluster(server).listen(4000) listen on port 4000 and automatically distribute incoming requests within a pool of worker servers? Or am I interpreting it wrong?

Comment: @shelman it does just that. It defaults a number of workers equal to the amount of processors